# Add 'Alt' key stoke to existing keystroke function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add the 'Alt' key stroke to existing keystroke function. I use this function to navigate pages but what I wold like to do is add the 'Alt' keystroke to all of the existing functions.

So instead of the single keystroke of lets say 'a' I would like it to work only with the keystroke of 'Alt+A' any help or ideas are greatly welcomed.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // hides all DIVs with the CLASS container
    // and displays the one with the ID 'home' only
    $(".container").css("display","none");
    $("#home").css("display","block");

    // makes the navigation work after all containers have bee hidden 
    showViaLink($("ul#navigation li a"));

    // listens for any navigation keypress activity
    $(document).keypress(function(e)
    {
        switch(e.which)
        {
            // user presses the "a"
            case 97:    showViaKeypress("#home");
                        break;  

            // user presses the "s" key
            case 115:   showViaKeypress("#about");
                        break;

            // user presses the "d" key
            case 100:   showViaKeypress("#contact");
                        break;

            // user presses the "f" key
            case 102:   showViaKeypress("#awards");
                        break;

            // user presses the "g" key 
            case 103:   showViaKeypress("#links");
        }
    });
});

// shows a given element and hides all others
function showViaKeypress(element_id)
{
    $(".container").css("display","none");
    // if multiple keys are pressed rapidly this will hide all but the last pressed key's div
    $(".container").hide(1);
    $(element_id).slideDown("slow");
}

// shows proper DIV depending on link 'href'
function showViaLink(array)
{
    array.each(function(i)
    {   
        $(this).click(function()
        {
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".container").css("display","none");
            $(target).slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like following using `altKey` in your `keypress` event like following.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.altKey) {
      switch(e.which)
      {
        // user presses the "a"
        case 97:    showViaKeypress("#home");
                    break;  

        // user presses the "s" key
        case 115:   showViaKeypress("#about");
                    break;

        // user presses the "d" key
        case 100:   showViaKeypress("#contact");
                    break;

        // user presses the "f" key
        case 102:   showViaKeypress("#awards");
                    break;

        // user presses the "g" key 
        case 103:   showViaKeypress("#links");
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've created this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azim101/dkk6twsc/. You need to add `e.preventDefault()` in your `keypress` event. @user1703803

Comment: OK I figure out the issue it works in Firefox but not in Chrome I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

So check for the alt key in the event Data. If pressed, it will be true.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   if (!e.altKey) return;
   /* rest of code */
});
```